# Spring Boot Caching with EhCache doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I'm using EhCache and Spring Boot to cache the HTTP response from the external API, but the cache doesn't seem to work.

I'm adding `Thread.sleep (2000);` to simulate the delay that should be skipped when using a cached response. But it is not, and with each method call, a delay and an external API are also called.

**Here is my cache configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    private static final String TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS = "transportLocations";
    private static final int TTL_MILLISECONDS = 15;

    @Bean
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration transportLocationCache = new CacheConfiguration();
        transportLocationCache.setName(TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS);
        transportLocationCache.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(1000);
        transportLocationCache.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        transportLocationCache.setTimeToLiveSeconds(TTL_MILLISECONDS);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(transportLocationCache);
        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }
}
```

**And method, which should be cached**

```
    @Cacheable(value = TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS, cacheManager = "cacheManager")
    public HttpResponse<String> sendTransportLocationsPostRequest(
            final LinkedHashMap<String, Object> bodyStructure,
            final String url)
            throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        final String body = buildBody(bodyStructure);
        final HttpRequest request = buildPostRequest(url, body);

        return client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
```

Do you have any idea, why this is not working?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some key to the Cacheable annotation ?

Comment: It doesn't work with key either. And I think that I don't need special key, when cache will have only one entry.

Comment: From the Cacheable documentation, if you don't specify a key, by default all method parameters are treated as key. Since you have hashmap as a method parameter, it could be that resolved key is always different. Have you tried with a key which remains same between method calls ?

Comment: Can you try with  #root.methodName as key ?

Comment: @SKumar Perfect! It's working! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When key is not specified in the Cacheable annotation, then all the method parameters are considered as a key which is happening here.

Refer - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html

> key -
> Default is "", meaning all method parameters are considered as a key, unless a custom keyGenerator() has been configured.

Since you only need single key in the TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS cache, you can specify method name as the key

```
@Cacheable(value = TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS, cacheManager = "cacheManager", key = "#root.methodName")
```